# Assign variable with punctuation in between it in lua

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I'm trying to write a script for DC++ hub based on Ptokax running on lua
i'm trying to assign the nick(a variable) which has punctuation in between but it gives nil values 
(sPattern is ! already assigned in script)

> sData = "[11:03:30]  !spm sTo_Nick sFromNick message to be sent"

```
cmd,sToNick1,sToNick2,sFromNick ,sMessage = string.match(sData, "%b<>%s["..sPattern.."](%a*)(%s+)(%w*)(%s+)(%w*)(%s+)(%.*)")
```

what i want to be assigned is

> cmd = spm
>   sToNick1 = sTo ,
>   sToNick2 = Nick ,
>   sFromNick = sFromNick , 
>   sMessage = message to be sent

what i'm getting is 
spm     sTo _   Nick

as can be seen here https://repl.it/BrAg/3

can anyone please suggest the edit or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rearrange the capture groups:

```
cmd,sToNick1,sToNick2,sFromNick,sMessage =
 string.match(sData, "%b<>%s["..sPattern.."](%a*)%s+(%w*)"..pattern.."(%w*)%s+(%w*)%s+(.*)")
```

See the [updated demo](https://repl.it/BrAg/5)

Comment: Note that Lua does not support regular expressions, these are called Lua patterns.